# How to display a HTML page as alert in jsp page?

Tags: java, html, jsp

We all know that there is method in HTML to display alert (`alert()` method).

But I want to display a HTML page as alert.

Comment: Correct me if I understood it wrong but won't it be like opening a new page or a new window?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ alert("Hi there"));}
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Hello world");
</script>
```

Comment: I want to display a HTML page as alert message in jsp.